# C# Serial port randomly return all 0 when overloaded

Tags: c#, winforms, uart

I am making a C# User Interface for a project using MCU communicate with the PC using UART. The string sent from the MCU in this format(3 numbers per group, 3 groups):

```
<number>,<number>,<number>,.<number>,<number>,<number>,.<number>,<number>,<number>,.\n
```

With each number can change depend on the MCU sending. I have written a program which work fine for this configuration. In general, it take in the data from COM port as a string, filter out any characters that is not a number, then save them separately into a List.

However, when we expand the format to use 7 numbers per group (21 in total):

```
<number>,<number>,<number>,<number>,<number>,<number>,<number>,.<number>,<number>,<number>,<number>,<number>,<number>,<number>,.<number>,<number>,<number>,<number>,<number>,<number>,<number>,.\n
```

When I try the same approach, there is some sort of "stagger" in the data in. When the data is stable, it is fine. When there is any rapid change in the number coming in, the graph of the data look like this:
[image]
The sharp drop in the middle of the graph is not how the data change; the UART port just "freeze up" and output 0 for all number in the receiving List, I have checked the data from [Hercules](https://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html) myself.
I think the problem come from overload since there is no differences in any other aspect between the 3 and 7 numbers datastream, but can StackOverflow users think of any other solution?
EDIT: Should it helps, here is the code I used:

```
// Initialization
static SerialPort mySerialPort;
string receiveMessage = "";
public delegate void AddDataDelegate(string text);
public AddDataDelegate DELEGATE_WRITE;
DELEGATE_WRITE = new AddDataDelegate(writeConsole);
// com and baud are defined variables
mySerialPort = new SerialPort(com, baud);
mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mySerialPort_datareceived);
mySerialPort.Open();

//Supporting functions
private void mySerialPort_datareceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string input = mySerialPort.ReadExisting();
    textBox.BeginInvoke(method: DELEGATE_WRITE, args: new Object[] { input });
}

public void writeConsole(string text)
{
    receiveMessage += text;
    // check if the receiving data steam is valid: end with '\n' and not longer than 64 characters (21 value of maybe 2-3 digits each)
    if (receiveMessage.Length > 64)
    {
        receiveMessage = "";
    }
    if (receiveMessage.Length > 0)
        if (receiveMessage[receiveMessage.Length - 1] == '\n')
        {
            updateInterface(receiveMessage);
            receiveMessage = "";
        }
    return;
}

void updateInterface(string input)
{
    try
    {
        int[] result = calculate(input);
        if (result == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error", caption: "Algorithm fail to extract data", buttons: MessageBoxButtons.OK, icon: MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
        }
//Save the data to List
}

static int[] calculate(string input)
{
    int[] outputs = new int[21];
    int index = 0;
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = input[i];
        if (c == '.')
        {
            int output = int.Parse(s);
            outputs[index] = output;
            index++;
            s = "";
        }
        else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9'|| c == '-')
        {
            s += c;
        }
     }
     return outputs;
  }
```

Comment: Most simple patch - add checksum for each line and ignore the data if checksum is wrong. BTW, it is better to use TAB for separator instead of comma.

Comment: What do you mean by _the UART port just "freeze up" and output 0 for all number in the receiving List_ - does it "freeze up" as in stop working or does it get all 0 data in the correct format? When you say "overload" how much data are you receiving?

Comment: @PaulF It get all 0 data in the correct format, which I guess, mean that is could not separate and save the data to List in time

Comment: @i486 Since all the comma is meant to do is just separate all the integers, why is it better to use \t (tab) instead?

Comment: @PaulF I guess it is overloaded because the code works fine when each data line only contain 9 numbers (3 groups of 3)

Comment: @NamNguyenHoang: I have collected data in much bigger quantities (1000s of bytes) from the UART without issue. (Also many different separators - the [original](http://www.asciitable.com/) ASCII characters defined several characters below SPACE (0x32) as separators, now rarely used - comma is just as good as tab) It may be useful if you can post your code (as an edit to the question) so we can see if it is a programming issue.

Comment: @NamNguyenHoang In your case comma will do the job for separator but generally it is better to use tab because comma can be part of the information (i.e. part of text, thousand separator, etc.).

Comment: @i486 In that case, maybe I should replace both of the separators (since '.' is used as thousand separator in other number system)? Use '\t' between numbers of the same group, '|' between groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always the devil is in the details

In the writeConsole function of my code, I make a check for valid string by checking if they end in '\n' (since the data will be coming in real time) and if they are less than 64 characters long (21 value of maybe 2-3 digits each). Turn out, that is not a correct assumption at all when the data  could easily reach twice as long when the data changed quickly enough (in my examples, the change could reach 100). So just delete the length check and the program work as usual.
PS: Come on guys, this is the second time I have to answer my own question already